# list subscriptions with Azure Resource Graph

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Is there any way of listing all authorized subscription by Azure resource graph (using rest API)?
Tried googling it and could not find a way

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Azure Resource Manager - List Subscriptions` REST API for that purpose. More information can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list.

Answer (score 0):

You can also access microsoft graph postman collection

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoftgraph-postman-collections

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do this in my application by querying all items and then getting a distinct list of subscription IDs.  It feels so wrong, but it works pretty well.